# How to set a content page or Item for a mobile device only in Sitecore 8.0?

Tags: sitecore-client, content-management, mobile

1) How to set a publishing target for mobile device only in Sitecore?

2) How to view a web page made for Device view without providing the query string (sc_device=mobile) for user use?

Please suggest.

Comment: I dont think it is possible to set up a publishing target for a single device. But for viewing the mobile site, I use the "User Agent Switch" chrome extension. It allows Sitecore to identify the browser as any device you want. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US

Comment: Hey Chris thanks for the suggestion. But I want to view the web page developed in sitecore for Device View in mobile device without using the query string, "sc_device=mobile" . Because when an user will check the web page in mobile he surely not gonna install the extension.

Comment: So you can turn on device detection in SItecore (https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/developing/device_detection/device_detection/set_up_device_detection) . Then Sitecore will do all the work. Or you can roll you own. https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/identifying-mobile-devices-in-sitecore/

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. So it will show the webpage in mobile devices right?

Comment: With device detection, Sitecore will know if you are on a mobile device and use the mobile device for you page, if you have it set for that page.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the answer from the comments:

Out of the box Sitecore is not able to detect mobile devices vs pads vs desktop. The easiest way to do it is to turn on device detection in Sitecore (https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/developing/device_detection/device_detection/set_up_device_detection). Then Sitecore will do all the work.

Or you can roll you own. https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/identifying-mobile-devices-in-sitecore/